# Detect Touchpad event in C++ Builder

Tags: callback, mouseevent, c++builder, touchpad

I am writing an API in C++ Builder that collects information for events on the touchpad of a windows laptop.
This is how I was doing it.

- I was creating a window
- when the touch pad is touched, I simply paint that information on that window in WM_PAINT event.

But now I dont want to create that window (form), i want to catch all the events, even if user is on desktop screen or on another application's window. If an application that is using my API is running in background i want to be able to get that touch even information in the code. How can I do that??
I hope you are getting my point ... actually i want to do it in a seamless way, otherwise that white form window will irritate the user. 
I also want to save these events in a link list and want to return that out of the API is it possible??
I will be very thankful for your time. I really need to work it out in next few hours.

Answer (score 3):

The touchpad is just a mouse like any other.  It generates standard mouse events.  Use a global `WH_MOUSE` hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` to capture mouse events globally.  To replay them, use `mouse_event()`.  Alternatively, use `WH_JOURNALRECORD` and `WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK` hooks instead for capture and playback, respectively.